# How to distinguish between map tasks in a single pig job

Tags: hbase, apache-pig

I am having Pig (0.10) load data from hdfs into hbase.  The raw records do not have unique rowkeys, so I have a UDF construct one:

```
public class Foo extends EvalFunc<Tuple> {
    // FIXME: If there are multiple map jobs for the same batch,
    // they will reuse the serial numbers.
    // Need to add something to figure out a distinct per task #
    private int task_id=0;
    private long serial=0L;

    public Tuple exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
            return null;
        try {
            Integer batch_id=(Integer)input.get(0);
            String rowkey=String.format("%7d%3d%9d", batch_id, task_id, serial++);
            // ... compute other values for the return Tuple.
        }
    }
}
```

My understanding is that if pig starts up two different map jobs for the same input data set (either due to exceeding the chunksize or from having multiple input files when LOADing from a directory,) each one is going to be a separate Java instance and thus there will be multiple independent copies of Foo.serial; my rowkeys will not be unique and I will be overwriting many of the records I am trying to load into HBase.

If my UDF can determine which of the mappers it is part of, the collisions go away.  I could fallback to IP address + process id, but that is rather wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Enumerate UDF in the [DataFu](https://github.com/linkedin/datafu) collection.  This will take a bag and assign each element a number 1 to N where N is the size of the bag.  The unfortunate side effect of this is that I believe all of your data will have to go through one reducer.  But from your description it sounds like this may not be a big issue. (It sounds like the data is only sometimes large enough to need to be split across multiple mappers.)

You can simply group all of your data into a single bag with `GROUP ... ALL`, and then enumerate this bag.  Then you can construct a custom row key using this number that will be unique for each record in the bag.

Comment: I am looking for a solution that avoids the one reducer bottleneck.  It is true that my current data is not huge and so fitting things so they go through a single mapper isn't too arduous,  I would like a technique that scales when big data has to be dealt with.